# What happens when the addChild, or removeChild method is called on a DisplayObjectContainer?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I would like to know the internals of that method, in other words what exactly happens when I call that method. If someone can explian it with a list 1,2,3... would be great.
including events..

and the addElement method too, if is possible.

thanks a lot!

Comment: If i am not wrong he is asking for what happens during the childrens creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two articles which might help you.

http://blog.deadinkvinyl.com/2008/10/05/flex-3-addchild-and-initialize/

Just see what happens during the addChild()

http://maohao.wordpress.com/2008/08/17/flex-101-addchild-and-removechild-event-order/